# Getting dollar amount after a word with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to decode some OCR on bet slips. The details I want is the stake of the bet which is always like this `Stake $10.00` or `$10.00 Stake`. Basically it will always be before or after the word Stake. Is it possible to regex once for either occurrence or will it need to be 2 regex patterns for the word Stake after or before.

Also some additional `Stake $5.00` might appear later in the OCR string but I will always want the first occurrence of it.

`/[\n\r].*Stake \s*([^\n\r]*)/`  Is as close as I get but I can't go *Stake $ because $ is used in regex. It also returns a second line which isn't `Stake` but not sure why it returns that

Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried, what failed? Any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First Version

```
(?<=Stake\s*)\$(\d*\.\d{0,2})|\$(\d*\.\d{0,2})(?=\s*Stake)
```

See  https://regex101.com/r/cc4fbT/1/

## Second Version

```
(?<=Stake\s*\$)\d*\.\d{0,2}|(?<=\$)\d*\.\d{0,2}(?=\s*Stake)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/cc4fbT/2/

#### Explanation

We are searching for either of the two [alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) patterns

```
(?<=Stake\s*\$)\d*\.\d{0,2}
```

and

```
(?<=\$)\d*\.\d{0,2}(?=\s*Stake)
```

Both have the matching pattern `\d*\.\d{0,2}` which is any number of digits, followed by a dot and up to two digits

The first pattern has a positive lookbehind and the second one has positive lookbehind as well as a lookahead
(https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which assert whether the pattern is preceded resp. succeeded by the pattern given.

So a translation into plain English would be: Check for a Dollar amount which either follows the phrase `Stake $` or is in between a `$` and the phrase  `Stake`

## Third version

If you don't want to use lookbehind (which does not work in Safari), you can use a mixture of non capturing and capturing groups.

```
(?:Stake\s*\$)(\d*\.\d{0,2})|(?:\$)(\d*\.\d{0,2})(?:\s*Stake)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/cc4fbT/4

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's using Next JS and from experience look behinds do not work in Safari. I'll have to test but i'm a bit concerned about this breaking. Thanks though works great!

Comment: @ThomasByy I elaborated a third version without using lookbehinds

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here you are! 
let str = "$1200 Stake";
let n = str.match(/([1-9]\d*(\.\d*[1-9])?|0\.\d*[1-9]+)/);
console.log(n[1]); // 1200

let str = "Stake $1300";
let n = str.match(/([1-9]\d*(\.\d*[1-9])?|0\.\d*[1-9]+)/);
console.log(n[1]); // 1300
```